# php insert key/value into associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to insert a couple of new Key/Value pairs into an associative array at a specific place. From other reading I've done on SO, I'm pretty sure I have to loop through the array and insert the new values when a condition is set.

Here is the current array

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Product' => array(
            'id' => '59',
            'title' => ' Blue Dress',
            'Review' => array(
                'id' => '7',
                'product_id' => '59',
                'Review' => array(
                    (int) 0 => array(
                        'average' => '3.0000'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Product' => array(
            'id' => '60',
            'title' => 'Red Dress',
            'Review' => array()
        )
    )
)
```

The key Review does not always have data, but when it does I want to insert a new key-value similar to the following excerpt

```
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Product' => array(
            'id' => '59',
            'title' => ' Blue Dress',
            'Review' => array(
                'id' => '7',
                'product_id' => '59',
                'Review' => array(
                    (int) 0 => array(
                        'average' => '3.0000'
                        'some_value' => '5'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

I've tried a few things without success.
Any help is much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
if(!empty($your_array[index]['Product']['Review'])){
  $your_array[index]['Product']['Review']['Review'][index]['some_value'] = 'new_value';
}
```

In your example it could be:

```
if(!empty($your_array[0]['Product']['Review'])){
  $your_array[0]['Product']['Review']['Review'][0]['some_value'] = 'new_value';
}
```

Again, you didn't mention your code. So, it's hard to figure out what you want exactly!

Comment: Thank you, that's it. Obvious really I wasn't thinking straight. I dont have a high enough reputation to upvote you .. otherwise I would.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through Your array and pass current value be reference:

```
// Notice & sign before variable
foreach ($data as &$product)
{
    if ($product['Product']['Review'])
    {
        // or iterate through Review array
        $product['Product']['Review']['Review'][0]['some_value'] = 5;
    }
}
```